# Executing shell script in Android app doesn't show results

Tags: android, linux, shell, command, root

I'm having trouble figuring out what is going on with my code. I'm trying to create a Profiles app. The device is rooted and contains BusyBox. I've written a linux script that swaps out the /data and /cache partitions depending on the user that logs in.

When I execute this script from ADB, it works perfectly. I figured implementing it in an app would be fairly easy.

# sp login username password

Android reinitializes with the new profile and all is good. This is what I have in Android:

```
Log.v("Profiles", "sp login " + user + " " + password);
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sp login " + user + " " + password);

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
int read;
char[] buffer = new char[4096];
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    output.append(buffer, 0, read);
}
reader.close();
process.waitFor();
Log.v("Profiles", output.toString());
```

The only out that is logged is my "echos" in the actual script itself. I don't get to see any results from the commands performed in that script. For example, when ran in ADB, all the mount commands and the different things I'm doing all have output. None of this is outputted in the output string.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If the `password` contains shell meta-characters such as `;` or `&` or `*` or `?` your `exec()` call may not execute as you expect. If Android gives you access to something more like `execve(2)` and less like `system(3)`, it'd be wise to use it. (Though I don't think that's related to your current problem.)

Comment: Nope. No special characters in the password. Just a simple string, although that is something I need to check for. Also, Android doesn't seem have execve, even though I don't really know much about that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute "su" for the process, which will execute your shell script.

Otherwise, this process didn't have the root permission even the device already rooted.

below code is an example for you reference.

```
public void RunAsRoot(String[] cmds){
    try{
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
        for(String tmpCmds : cmds){
            os.writeBytes(tmpCmds+"\n");
            os.flush();
            os.writeBytes("exit\n");
            os.flush();
        }
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

       // read the output from the command
       String s = null;
       while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(s);
       }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "RunAsRoot exec failed");
    }
```

}